# Spring MVC - After end of result set (SQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm trying to send in ORDER table last ID from CUSTOMER and all IDs from PRODUCT tables. In "idproduct"(ORDER table) should appears all IDs with white spaces between them. I used here `rs.next()` twice and I know that it isthe reason why error appears, but how can I handle it? Here is a code:

```
List<String> IDproducts = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection conn = db.getConnect();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `onlineshop`.`customer`");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            rs.getString(1);
        }

        Connection conn1 = db.getConnect();
        PreparedStatement pst1 = conn1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `onlineshop`.`product`");
        ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();

        while (rs1.next()){
            IDproducts.add(rs1.getString(1));
        }

        db.Query("INSERT INTO `onlineshop`.`order` (`idcustomer`, `idproduct`) 
        VALUES ('"+rs.getString(1)+"','" + IDproducts + ")");
```

error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:862)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5244)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5167)
```

Comment: "After end of result set", I editet post

Comment: which line is the error in the code? I don't see `rs.next()` twice in the code that you showed.